# How to get first 2 words?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let `data.title` be ABC XYZ PQRS - www.aaa.tld.
Output needs to be like this ABC+XYZ

i've tried this:

```
var t = data.title.split(' ').join('+');
t = t.replace(/(([^\s]+\s\s*){1})(.*)/,"Unknown");
 $("#log").text(t);
```

Comment: Do you always want the *first* two words?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a regex?  Seems a simple split+concat would suffice:  `var x = data.title.split(' ');var t = x[0] + "+" + x[1];`

Comment: Just be aware if your string starts getting over 1MB a regex function for this can still handle this in a millionth of a second where the split join starts slowing down to hundredths or tenths of a second. Considering punctuation or other white space characters is another reason you might want to use regex. Split join does make it easy to change from space to '+'.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, no regex though, it only grabs the first two words and must have a space between those words.

First we split into and array, then we slice that array from the 0 index to 2(exclusive) or 1, and finally we join them with a '+':

```
var x = 'ABC XYZ PQRS';

var y = x.split(' ').slice(0,2).join('+');

// y = "ABC+XYZ"
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsbin.com/carajo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: You could also make the split a bit more robust by splitting on any number of whitespace characters like so `x.split(/\s+/).slice(0,2).join('+');`

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.match()` with `RegExp` `/([\w+]+)/g`; concatenate first match, `+` character, second match

```js
var matches = "ABC XYZ PQRS - www.aaa.tld".match(/([\w+]+)/g);
console.log(matches[0] + "+" + matches[1])
```

Comment: Asked for words, not letters. well this one is also great.

Comment: @JonyS `.split(" ")` will also match any characters at indexes 0 and 1

Comment: Thanks bruh :) @guest271314

Comment: @JonyS _"Asked for words, not letters."_ See updated post

Comment: can you explain this RegExp ? @guest271314

Comment: Good. But doesn't work with non-latin characters

Answer (score 0):

This is my general function for first n words. Haven't tested it extensively but it is fast even on long strings because it doesn't use a global regex or split every word. You can fine tune the regex for dealing with punctuation. I'm considering a hyphen as a delimiter but you can move that to the word portion instead if you prefer.

```
function regFirstWords(s, n) {
    // ?: non-capturing subsequent sp+word.Change {} if you want to require n instead of allowing fewer
    var a = s.match(new RegExp('[\\w\\.]+' + '(?:[\\s-]*[\\w\\.]+){0,' + (n - 1) + '}')); 
    return  (a === undefined || a === null) ? '' : a[0];
}
```

To satisfy the OP's request to replace with '+'

```
regFirstWords('ABC XYZ PQRS - www.aaa.tld',2).replace(/\s/g,'+')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using the Split Method**
One straightforward method involves using the split method, which allows us to split a string into an array of substrings based on a specified delimiter. In this case, we can split the string using a space (' ') as the delimiter and then extract the first N elements from the resulting array.

```
    function getFirstNWords(inputString, n) {
  const wordsArray = inputString.split(' ');
  const firstNWords = wordsArray.slice(0, n).join(' ');
  return firstNWords;
}

// Example usage:
const originalString = "JavaScript provides versatile methods for manipulating strings.";
const result = getFirstNWords(originalString, 5);
console.log(result);
```